Nuxt 3 app can not connect to database using SQL Server
I can not connect to the database using nuxt js and SQL Server
my error:

Database connection failed: sql.connect is not a function
at connectToDatabase (server\db\index.ts:21:24)
at sqlQuery (server\db\index.ts:38:24)
at blogModel.read (server\model\blog.ts:31:10)
at Object.read (server\controller\blog.ts:7:1)

Code:
//my index.ts
import * as sql from 'mssql';

const config = {
  user: 'myuser', // Your database username
  password: 'mypassword', // Your database password
  server: 'mydatabase.database.windows.net', // Server name for Azure SQL Database
  database: 'mydb', // Your database name
  options: {
    encrypt: true, // Use encryption
    enableArithAbort: true // Enable ArithAbort
  }
};

let pool: sql.ConnectionPool | null = null;

export const connectToDatabase = async (): Promise<sql.ConnectionPool> => {
  try {
    if (!pool) {
      pool = await sql.connect(config);
      console.log('Connected to SQL Server database');
    }
    return pool;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Database connection failed:', err);
    throw err;
  }
};

interface QueryOptions {
  query: string;
  values?: any[];
}

export const sqlQuery = async ({ query, values }: QueryOptions): Promise<any[]> => {
  try {
    const pool = await connectToDatabase();
    const request = pool.request();

    if (values) {
      values.forEach((value, index) => {
        request.input(`param${index + 1}`, value);
      });
    }

    const result = await request.query(query.replace(/\?/g, (match, i) => `@param${i + 1}`));
    return result.recordset;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('SQL query error:', err);
    throw err;
  }

// blog.ts (server/model/blog.ts)

import { sqlQuery } from '~~/server/db/index';

interface Blog {
  id?: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
}

export const create = async (blog: Blog): Promise<number> => {
  const query = `
    INSERT INTO Blogs (title, content)
    VALUES (?, ?)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id
  `;
  const result = await sqlQuery({
    query,
    values: [blog.title, blog.content]
  });
  return result[0].id;
};

export const read = async (): Promise<Blog[]> => {
  const query = `
    SELECT id, title, content
    FROM Blogs
  `;
  return sqlQuery({ query });
};

export const detail = async (id: string): Promise<Blog> => {
  const query = `
    SELECT id, title, content
    FROM Blogs
    WHERE id = ?
  `;
  const result = await sqlQuery({ query, values: [id] });
  return result[0];
};

export const update = async (id: string, blog: Blog): Promise<void> => {
  const query = `
    UPDATE Blogs
    SET title = ?, content = ?
    WHERE id = ?
  `;
  await sqlQuery({ query, values: [blog.title, blog.content, id] });
};

export const remove = async (id: string): Promise<void> => {
  const query = `
    DELETE FROM Blogs
    WHERE id = ?
  `;
  await sqlQuery({ query, values: [id] });
};

What is wrong? Please help. I do not know what to do. I imported mssql package with yarn.
I excepted to make basic crud app with nuxt and SQL Server, but it is not working.
